# Magento 2 - Pass Currency Param in URL

Tags: magento2, currency, parameter, querystring

I want to add Currency parameter in Magento 2 page URL.Like

www.example.com/product.html?currency=GBP

Is there any way to do this?
Need help.Thanks

**EDIT: Created a plugin but not working**

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Digital_CurrencyCodeAddress_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Product_Url" sortOrder="10" type="Digital\CurrencyCode\Plugin\ProductUrl"/>
    </type>        
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Digital_CurrencyCode" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Digital_CurrencyCode',
    __DIR__
);
```

ProductUrl.php

```
<?php
namespace Digital\CurrencyCode\Plugin;

class ProductUrl 
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager       
    ){

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function beforeGetUrl(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url $subject,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
            $params = []
    ) {

        if(empty($params) || (!empty($params) && !array_key_exists('_query', $params))){

            if(!array_key_exists('_query', $params)){
                $params['_query'] = [];
            }
            if(!array_key_exists('currency', $params['_query'])){
                 $params['_query']['currency'] =$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
            }

        }

        return [
            $product,
            $params
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working good..I can see the currency added in category page when i click that it will go to product page asusual with currency code

Comment: did you checked log?

Comment: How you checked?

Comment: Yes.. i have used the same code

Comment: What's the link?

Comment: It's in my local environment

Comment: Have you checked whether the module is enabled?

Comment: Yes, module is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99610/discussion-between-aravind-and-shoaib-saleem).

Comment: Can you check that it's working fine when change currency directly from URL?Website currency should be update.